# Git lab build fails with 403 error

Tags: gitlab-ci

i am trying to set up gitlab runner for a project, and when i try to run the build i am getting an 403 error.
Where can i check the build logs other than doing systemctl status gitlab-runner?

git-lab-runner Version:      9.5.1

**build error:**

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 9.5.1 (96b34cc)
  on ci (3aa5e67d)
Using Docker executor with image docker.xxx.com/terraform:latest ...
Using docker image sha256:134722953932eb772ab67a8b6e865aae2da7fe6ba3f09e757ea09e0d416ec203 for predefined container...
Pulling docker image docker.xxx.com/terraform:latest ...
Using docker image docker.xxx.com/terraform:latest ID=sha256:fxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx for build container...
Running on runner-3aa5e67d-project-184-concurrent-0 via ip-10-xx-xx-xx...
    Cloning repository...
    Cloning into '/builds/bi/abc'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.xxxx.com/folder/abc.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
    ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

runner config:

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[[runners]]
  name = "ci"
  url = "http://gitlab.xxx.com"
  token = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker.xxx.com/terraform:latest"
    privileged = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/cache"]
    shm_size = 0
  [runners.cache]
```

I had configured gitlab runner to a different project but it did not ask me to add the user to the members, how can i troubleshoot this error, i believe its an authentication error.